# How to build a DLL with custom file extension in a C# project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

Is there any way to compile a C# DLL project (visual studio) into a file with a custom extension? for example plugin.cpx instead of plugin.dll (cpx = **C**ustom **P**lugin e**X**tension!)

And can I use any extension I want?

Comment: Very unclear what problem this is supposed to solve.  Changing the name to plugin.cpx.dll is the trivial approach.

Comment: @HansPassant I mean doing it automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*I'm adding this as a new answer because it is just that. And it's a lot easier than my earlier offering, in many ways.*</sup>

You can explicitly specify the target extension by manually editing the project's `.csproj` file.

In "Solution Explorer," right click on the project and select the "Unload project" command. Then, right-click again and select "Edit MyProject.csproj" (where "MyProject" would be the actual name, obviously).

To make the extension change apply to **all** configurations and/or platforms, add the following three lines, near the top of the file (just before the first of the other `PropertyGroup` entries):

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetExt>.cpx</TargetExt>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then save the file, close it, and "Reload" the project (again, *via* a right-click in the Solution Explorer).

*To change the extension only for a specific configuration or platform, add the `TargetExt` line inside the `PropertyGroup` relevant to that configuration.*

Comment: Good but not for me. Seems that my .csproj file is not in 'old' format. I searched for both "TargetExt" and "dll" but couldn't find any useful thing.

Comment: @AmirSinaMashayekh There won't be any `TargetExt` stuff in the file by default. Do you have any `<PropertyGroup>` xml-style lines in the file?

Comment: Yes. Many of them.

Comment: @AmirSinaMashayekh And if you insert the three lines above just before the first, what happens? Nothing? Or does the project then fail to load or build?

Answer (score 1):

> And can I use any extension I want?

Yes, you can, but it's a bit 'tricky'.

For C# projects, you will need to add a custom "Post Build Event" to rename the output file. For a DLL project (as yours is) you can add a post-build command like that shown below, in the "Build Events" tab of the "Properties" window:

[image]

Note: Be sure to use the `$(TargetName)` macro, *not* `$(TargetFileName)`, as the latter will implicitly include the `.dll` extension. But you could use:

```
rename "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetName).cpx"
```

**EDIT:** Also, you will need to tell the builder to delete any old version of the `.cpx` file, at some stage. This could be done as a pre-build event, as follows:

```
IF EXIST "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).cpx" del "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).cpx"
```

Without this, the attempt to rename the output file will fail (as the new 'target' will already exist).

**EDIT-2:** As noted in the comment by the OP, without the `"` quotes, the pre- and post-build commands will fail if there are spaces in the file paths.

Comment: Sorry but would you explain it better? I'm using VS-2019. I right clicked on project but there was no "Advanced" option. Then I selected "Properties" and project properties "tab" (not window as you sent) opened. it is like what you sent but there is no "General" or "Advanced" there. There is an "Advanced..." button in "Properties>Build" but there isn't anything about file extension there.

Comment: And my project is in C# (WPF). not C++.

Comment: @AmirSina See edit (you didn't originally include the C# tag, but I was working on adding the option, anyway).

Comment: @AdrianI Thanks. I thought  the method is same for any project type. Please edit your answer like this: `IF EXIST "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).cpx" del "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).cpx"` and `rename "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll" $(TargetName).cpx`; if there is a space character in file path or file name, it will make error without quotation marks.

Comment: @AmirSina Thanks very much for pointing out the need for the " quotes - see latest edit.

Comment: @AmirSinaMashayekh I think I found a better way - see my other answer!! :)